# How to save a page state?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

In a Windows Runtime app, I load data like this:

```
private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    var userId = e.NavigationParameter as string;
    List<User> followers = GetFollowers(userId);
    this.DefaultViewModel["Followers"] = followers;
}
```

then user can select an item from `ListView`:

```
private void ContentListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = e.ClickedItem as User;

    if (!Frame.Navigate(typeof(FollowersPage), selectedItem.UserId))
    {
        throw new Exception(this.resourceLoader.GetString("NavigationFailedExceptionMessage"));
    }
}
```

So it navigates forward to the same page, but shows new followers.

The problem is that when it navigates back, it loads data again and shows from the beginning of the list rather than showing the last item selected.

So how to save a `List` of data in `NavigationHelper_SaveState` and how to load it again in `NavigationHelper_LoadState` with last position in the list? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic semi-tested example you can start from. You'll need to modify it to fit your exact circumstances. Some of it is adapted from [here](http://codeiuse.tumblr.com/post/85391658023/save-to-and-restore-scroll-position-in-a-listview).

```
void NavigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
{
    var isp = (ItemsStackPanel)listview.ItemsPanelRoot;
    int firstVisibleItem = isp.FirstVisibleIndex;
    e.PageState["FirstVisibleItemIndex"] = firstVisibleItem;

    // This must be serializable according to the SuspensionManager
    e.PageState["Followers"] = this.DefaultViewModel["Followers"];
}

void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    // Do we have saved state to restore?
    if (e.PageState != null)
    {
        // Restore list view items
        this.DefaultViewModel["Followers"] = (WhateverType)e.PageState["Followers"];

        // Restore scroll offset
        var index = (int)e.PageState["FirstVisibleItemIndex"];
        var container = listview.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        listview.ScrollIntoView(container);
    }
    else
    {
        // Load data for the first time
        var userId = e.NavigationParameter as string;
        List<User> followers = GetFollowers(userId);
        this.DefaultViewModel["Followers"] = followers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. I think it was possible to add our custom type to SuspensionManager so it knows the type and can deal with it?